# Compare constant equals object or object equal constant

Tags: java, coding-style

Follow Java [best-java-coding-practices.htm](http://www.groupkt.com/post/5bcd8475/javalangstring-tips-and-tricks:-best-java-coding-practices.htm), they say we need call `.equals` on known string constants rather than **UNKNOWN variable**

```
String string = new Test().getString();
// always compare like this, this will never throw NPE
System.out.println("CONSTANT.equals(string):"+CONSTANT.equals(string));
System.out.println("Comparision like string.equals(CONSTANT) may throw NullPointerException");
// next statement will throw NPE
System.out.println("string.equals(CONSTANT):"+string.equals(CONSTANT));
```

So how about **KNOWN variable**? Should we still use this way or not?

For example, if I receive an object from server and server notify that this object **never** null.
In case I want to compare this object with a constant

```
// CONS: it may return NPE if server return null (for example server do wrong) => app crash
// PRO: when we read this code, we have a mindset that object never null, if it null it is the server bug
object.equals(CONSTANT)

// CONS: When we read this code, we never know why and when object == null so it confusing. 
// It not return NPE so code still running and we may have some problem with UI or logic
// PRO: it never return NPE
CONSTANT.equals(object)
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. For me, I prefer `object.equals(CONSTANT)` for known variable but my team not.

**UPDATE** I think

```
CONSTANT.equals(object)
```

similar too

```
try{
   object.equals(CONSTANT)
catch(NullPointerException ex){
   // don't handle or explain anything
}
```

Comment: Stick to CONSTANT.equals(object). Especially because, what is a known variable? How can you be sure to know it? It still can be null due to special circumstances.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based. I would check for null and handle that case before comparing. Since Java allows null values it's a good idea to use them.

Comment: Aside from the fact `CONST.equals(var)` is guaranteed to not result in a NPE, it makes literally no difference. Don't split hairs with your team. Get on with some important stuff.

Comment: @Korashen Exactly. There is no such thing.

Comment: This question is off-topic (opinion based). This maybe a bit related: [What is the proper way to use a .equals method in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12486977)

Comment: what's the reason for prefering `object.equals(CONSTANT)` ? I would follow the code-style of your team.

Comment: @fairtrax sorry for my bad explain but I think I already explain it in my code, please check it again and also please see my update

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I agree that this is opinion-based, but let me just agree with your opinion:-) Some people just don't wanna see NPE no matter what, they treat it like a plague. For example, going to an obsessive use of Optional when they can get NoSuchElementException instead of NullPointerException which is basically the same. It is really a case by case thing. In the context where you know your variable should not be null then you shouldn't put misleading tricks like CONSTANT.equals(string). It's way better to get an NPE if a case doesn't follow the assumption. It's the fail-fast approach.

Comment: @Korashen "It still can be null due to special circumstances" - the question is basically saying that "special circumstances" is a bug, so you suggest "swallowing" bugs?

Comment: @Phan Van Linh: runtime exception should be avoided by developer. try catch block is less readable, rather use if-null-clause with handling/logging a wrong message from server. The question is, where to check, if server sent everything correctly - inside your method or not? Depends on architecture of your application and the responsibilities of classes.
BTW, in Java 8, there is a `@NonNull` annotation. If you annotate your method input with it, the compiler forces to avoid passing any possible null value.

Comment: @PhanVanLinh just a suggestion to make your team happy - try to suggest using asserts (e.g. Spring Assert methods or your own, but not java built-in asserts as they are generally disabled on most environments). In this case you would check the variable only once in the constructor or your method and then work with it without special tricks.

Comment: @Ruslan The question states, that the object is provided by a server. So you get your data from a foreign system. You must expect every possible value, also null, to be provided from that. So if a foreign server states, that it will never provide null, but still does send you a null, it is a Bug, yes, but in the server, not in your application. In respect of robustnes, you should go with a null check and not relay on statements from foreign systems. The but itself must be analyzed and fixed on the server side.

Comment: @Korashen, I agree with this last comment of yours: "In respect of robustnes, you should go with a null check". I upvoted it :) But I still disagree with "Stick to CONSTANT.equals(object)". Those are really different approaches. The former is an explicit null check that clearly shows the intention to the reader of the code while the latter is an expression trick that hides the intention of assuming a possibility of null.

Comment: @PhanVanLinh an update to my comment about assertions: also you could suggest to you team to use the standard java.util.Objects#requireNonNull()

Comment: @Ruslan @Korashen thank you so much for your suggestion. Now I agree with this question is primarily opinion based. I will try to tell my team `requireNonNull()`. However, finally I still keep my opinion ;). I will still use `object.equals(constant)` **if I know or server tell me this object never null** because I want to handle all case that may happened with my code ^^.

Comment: Somebody tell me that is very small problem but I think it may a big problem in some case like ^^
`if(constant.equal(object)){
  updateDataBase();
}else{
  deleteDataBase();
}`

Answer (score 1):

The practice of reversing the terms around the equality operator when one of the terms is a constant is called a ***Yoda conditional***. You might encounter it in the following forms:

- `if( constant == variable )` instead of `if ( variable == constant )`
- `if( constant.equals( variable ) )` instead of `if( variable.equals( constant ) )`

Do not use Yoda conditionals. The Principle of Least Surprise is not just violated by this construct, it is gang-raped.

Also, this is a form of "defensive programming". Do not engage in defensive programming; engage in offensive programming instead. Read [Trevor Jim's post Postel's law is not for you](http://trevorjim.com/postels-law-is-not-for-you).

Also, do not blindly follow some advice just because someone calls it a "best practice". Who says it is a best practice?

- Is it just a couple of folks out there? then by definition, they are not entitled to dress their subjective opinion with an objective title like "best practice".
- Is it the majority of the industry? The majority is usually wrong. (Some might even say ***always*** wrong, watch [Paul Rulkens @ TEDxMaastricht 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNGFep6rncY&t=15s))
- Is it virtually everyone in the industry? Then clearly, the industry is engaging in [groupthink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink).

Here are the reasons often cited for using Yoda conditionals, and their rebuttals:

- Alleged reason #1

  - ***Statement:*** It will catch accidental use of the assignment operator where the equality operator was intended.
  - ***Rebuttal:*** Such accidental use should be impossible because your compiler or your IDE should be issuing a warning if you try to do this. If you are not receiving a warning, then you have other, much bigger problems in need of solving, i.e. using the wrong programming language, using the wrong IDE, or trying to write code without first having figured out how to enable all warnings.
- Alleged reason #2

  - ***Statement:*** It works even if the variable accidentally happens to be `null`.
  - ***Rebuttal:*** No, it does not work; it silently fails. If you follow offensive programming, the definition of "it works" is that *it must produce correct results when given valid input, and it must deliberately fail when given invalid input.* So, there are two possibilities: either the variable may legitimately be `null`, or it may not.

    - if the variable may legitimately be `null`, then explicitly check against `null`.
    - if the variable may not be `null`, then write the code so that it will not fail to fail in the event that the variable is in fact `null`.